# Not able to install MSI installer on windows 10 64 bit machine

Tags: windows-installer

[image]

When I am trying to install a MSI file it is showing above error message.

Comment: I cropped the screenshot to a reasonable size. Hope it's okay, please add some more information. (for example your WiX source file `.wxs`)

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking this is off topic as you aren't the developer of the installer. That makes this an end user problem.    That said, without looking at said MSI or installer log  it's pretty obvious the developer has a gate check defect.  Most likely in the LaunchConditions table.  You'll need to download ORCA.MSI and after installing it, use it to edit the MSI in question to strip out the check.  Hopefully it doesn't have other compatibility issues.

Otherwise as an end user you should go back to the vendor of that product and report a bug and have them fix it.

Comment: It's working on  windows 7 and it's not working only on windows 10, I am the developer I developed this,

Comment: Actually my question is w.r.t to Windows 10 , even though I have IIS 10 I am not able to install a MSI

Comment: I would have never guessed you were the developer as you merely called it "a" MSI and didn't provide any wix source code or installer log.  Please include the portion of your code that you use to do the IIS and Windows checks.

Comment: Your launch conditions are incorrect. As has been said, it's not possible to diagnose the problem unless you actually tell people what they are, how you defined them, whether your setup is x86 or x64 and so on.